# Could super cooled helium freeze a swimming pool

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, water, thermal-conductivity

Theoretically, would it be possible for a grenade like capsule with super cooled helium inside, be able to freeze a standard Olympic swimming pool if set off in the middle of said pool in any circumstance?( that could be plausibly replicated on earths surface) If not what would it take for aforementioned helium to freeze a swimming pool?

Answer (score 2):

You could freeze a swimming pool with liquid helium, although it would take an awful lot of it and be rather expensive.

Helium is useful for cooling things because it is very cold, it has the lowest boiling point of any element. But it has a very very small heat of vapourisation - it takes very little energy to boil liquid helium, and so it extracts very little energy from the thing it is cooling.

Unfortunatley water has a very high specific heat capacity - it takes a lot of energy to heat water 1 deg C - so you also have to extract a lot of energy to cool water by 1deg C. It also takes a lot of energy to melt ice - which means you have to extract a lot of energy to cool water into ice.

edit: it takes 2500000 * (4200*20 + 333000) = 1,000,000,000,000 J to freeze the pool. At 21 KJ/Kg for boiling liquid helium it would use around 50M kg of Liquid helium which costs around 100-150 $/kg

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was straight forward, very thorough and close to my specific question. Although,  I would ask if I was to dramatically increase the pressure on all of the pools surface area beforehand would it make a difference in the effectiveness of the heliums ability to change the specific heat capacity of the water.  As well, could you detonate such a "capsule" in a controlled manur. Anyway, this has settled a very complex debate and I appreciate your time and effort in this.  Feel free to ignore the other questions just simple curiosity.

Comment: Why are you only considering the heat of vaporization of helium?  I'm not sure how it behaves at low temps, but at higher temperatures, gaseous helium has a good specific heat capacity as well.  Obviously you'll take a hit because the mass/density of helium is far less than of the water; but the helium also has a much higher temperature difference to release the energy.

Comment: @JMac very few swimming pools have the enclosed pressure vessels to contain the rapid vapourisation of 50,000 ton of He and efficiently cycle the gas back through the water - obviously this would only be practical for an open-air pool

Comment: @MartinBeckett Fair enough.  I probably would have gone to the opposite extreme with it and factored that in (just to show that even best case scenario numbers probably still suck).   That would have been my approach based off OPs wording of "_Theoretically, would it be possible... ... in any circumstance?( that could be plausibly replicated on earths surface)_"

Comment: @jmac, don't know if the specific heat of He is high at low T, I did discover that the liquid heat capacity spikes at superfluidity (didn't know that). Normally we tried to get the gas out of instruments quickly to stop a pressure build up , rather than try and use it for extra cooling.